# External USB drive freezes, Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, usb-drive, freeze

I have a western digital USB drive connected to a Jetson Xavier via an ATOLLA USB 3.0 Hub.  The usb drive works for quite a while, but then stops working.  In order to get the drive to start working again I either (a) reboot, or (b) reflash, or (c) press the third button on the Xavier which may do a soft restart.  After restart, then there is a stopped job, Device Manager.

Is there a way to diagnose the frozen drive, and can this be corrected?

Here is some additional information.

uname -a
Linux john-desktop 4.9.201-tegra #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Mar 2 19:53:23 PST 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

dmsg

[   82.379300] usb 2-4.1.1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using tegra-xusb
[   82.400212] usb 2-4.1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=0827
[   82.400272] usb 2-4.1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[   82.400280] usb 2-4.1.1: Product: My Passport 0827
[   82.400286] usb 2-4.1.1: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[   82.400292] usb 2-4.1.1: SerialNumber: 575848314538353935373337
[   82.403990] usb-storage 2-4.1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   82.404645] scsi host2: usb-storage 2-4.1.1:1.0
[   83.419655] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Passport 0827 1012 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[   83.421638] scsi 2:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1012 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[   83.423595] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
[   89.557763] .
[   89.557965] ready
[   89.558319] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 1953458176 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
[   89.559023] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[   89.559142] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
[   89.559705] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[   89.559850] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[   89.606394] sda: sda1 
[   89.610931] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[   93.129436] rtl_usb:rtl_usb_resume [rtl_usb]:<10100-1> Too short packet from bulk IN! (len: 37)
[  276.195373] rtl_usb:rtl_usb_resume [rtl_usb]:<10000-1> Too short packet from bulk IN! (len: 1)
[  342.745113] rtl_usb:rtl_usb_resume [rtl_usb]:<10000-1> Too short packet from bulk IN! (len: 24)
[  356.378482] rtl_usb:rtl_usb_resume [rtl_usb]:<10000-1> Too short packet from bulk IN! (len: 34)
[  386.101117] rtl_usb:rtl_usb_resume [rtl_usb]:<10000-1> Too short packet from bulk IN! (len: 34)
.
.
.
[ 1595.469238] rtl_usb:rtl_usb_resume [rtl_usb]:<10000-1> Too short packet from bulk IN! (len: 43)
[ 1635.355070] rtl_usb:rtl_usb_resume [rtl_usb]:<10000-1> Too short packet from bulk IN! (len: 52)
[ 1978.011522] rtl_usb:rtl_usb_resume [rtl_usb]:<10000-1> Too short packet from bulk IN! (len: 33)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the cable from the USB 3 hub to the external USB hard drive and now everything works fine.